# WHich framework should i use for building ecommerce site in Python

Tags: python, frameworks

I have chosen Python as a langauge to build my ecommerce webiste.

The site will contains

```
1)Logins
2)registration
3)SHop Cart
4)Payment gateway
5)Admin can edit some content pages
```

I have started learning basic python.

But i want to build website and i have to start with one framework

the web users can vary fromm 100's to 1000's

SO which Framework will be best . I have to use some Machine learning tools using python on some webistes.

Will Django be enough for me

Comment: Most e-commerce software packages are written in either PHP or Java. That is not to say you shouldn't use Python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I bet you already reviewed your choices:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

If you understand the value proposition of using SQLAlchemy (as compared to being forced to do "ActiveRecord" style database (non)abstraction) stick with those platforms that offer native support for SQLAlchemy. Mastering it = half of your business logic becomes portable to any Python platform or database type.

If you want to "slap something together" go with Django.

If you know you will stay the course until you are done, take a strong look at Pylons and stick with it if you can stomach the extra effort. It will give you more freedom than Django, at a cost of more coding.

Take special note of web2py and go for it if the special benefits it provides (see their video presentation) are worth the limitations.

Twisted will look technically interesting to you, but go for it only if you are a masochist.

Either way. Good luck.

On a related note, there is a movement out there to separate "shopping cart + check out" from the page-serving framework. One good example is http://www.ecwid.com/  It provides javascript that you put in your regular site. That javascript pull the entire shopping cart system into customer's browser directly from ecwid.com. However, all of that is presented on top of your site's actual "shop" page. I work in payment processing industry (not in the ecwid.com) and messing around with your own payment pages and security is a pain. Might as well outsource the payment glue to a processor and concentrate on presentation, merchandise, customer service.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/) for building e-commerce sites in Django.

If your needs aren't that complex I'd give [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) a look.

Comment: Shopify is a hosted solution. The OP wants to build his own.

Comment: @TomDworzanski That's why I listed Satchmo.  It didn't seem like he really needed a custom ecommerce site, so I mentioned Shopify to save him hundreds of hours of headaches.  I don't care about the points; it's just silly that you downvoted me.

Comment: The down-vote is because the answer is wrong and because you named Shopify with no justification as to why it should be used over any other hosted shopping cart solutions. Your answer makes it sound like Shopify is a framework in line with the others mentioned. It's not. If you just said "If your needs are simple, you could use a hosted shopping cart," I would have up-voted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

framework choice won't limit you. You can use **any** framework and still do all those things.